# notepad++ replace text with get some text

Tags: regex, windows, replace, notepad++

Hello i want replace this text :

```
test.myfonction(arg1, arg2)
test2.myfonction(arg1, arg2)
test3.myfonction(arg1, arg2)
```

by this:

```
myfonction2(test, arg1, arg2)
myfonction2(test2, arg1, arg2)
myfonction2(test3, arg1, arg2)
```

for this, i use regex in notepad++, for find Something.mafonction(arg1, arg2)
i use this:

```
(*).myfonction(
```

but how get test, test or test3 ?

```
myfonction2(test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to capture the string before the `.`, the function name and the parameters:

```
(\w+)\.(\w+)\(([^\)]+)\)
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/oO0rB7/1)

Now you have three groups:

1. the first string
2. the function name
3. the arguments

And you can use it to replace the string for your desired output:

```
\2\(\1, \3\)
```

Comment: thak's for you answer, it's not totaly correct, because i have this: `myfonction(test, arg1, arg2myfonction()
test2, arg1, arg2myfonction()
test3, arg1, arg2)` 
I think it's a newline problem , I'm watching .

Comment: I updated my regex and replacement. Please try again.

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, you don't need to write [solved] on the header because if you accept the answer, its been marked as solved anyway. Another hint: If you need another replacement function with notepad++, add the `regex` tag to your question and you will reach much more developers.

Comment: Instead of marking as solved, accept an answer by clicking the big green check on the left of it